# Ordenar por categoria

Tags: php, mvc

Seguinte galera já revirei essa comunidade e consegui algumas fontes agradáveis porém não me ajudou, estou tentando separar meus links por categorias que também estão guardadas no banco de dados.

Se alguém tiver um tutorial pra me passar agradeço.

Veja os prints abaixo

1º print tabela de categoria
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2º print tabela de links
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3º print home page do site
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na terceira imagem, não está separando por categorias está uma bagunça tremenda, agora vamos aos códigos:

Meu model:

```
<?php

class Docs_Model extends Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getCategories() {
        return $this->_db->read('SELECT * FROM ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'cats', array());
    }

    public function getDocsCategories() {

        $data = $this->getCategories();

        $arr = [];

        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $arr = $value;
        }

        //return $this->_db->read('SELECT * FROM ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'docs WHERE id_cat=:id', array(
        //  ':id' => $arr['id_cat']
        //));

        return $this->_db->read('SELECT * FROM ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'docs c1, ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'docs c2 WHERE c1.id_cat = 1 AND c1.id_cat = c2.id_cat', array(
            //':idcat' => $arr['id_cat']
            ));
    }


}
```

Minha view:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php foreach($data['cats'] as $key => $value): ?>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                    <?php foreach($data['docs'] as $key2 => $value2): ?>
                      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $value2['title'] ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

Se precisar de mais informações eu disponho, espero ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Depende do link que você quer apontar. Para que comuns não se repitam  você pode usar algo em torno disso

```
return $this->_db->read('SELECT * FROM ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'cats GROUP BY id_cat', array()); // Agrupamento pelo codigo da categoria.
```

Avançando mais pesquise sobre SUB-SELECT

Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM tabela
ORDER BY id_cliente DESC
) AS retorno
GROUP BY id_cat
LIMIT 4
```

Complementando a ajuda

Referência que pode te dar um norte.

Basicamente, pelo que entendi, você irá trazer os nomes das categorias e com a subconsulta trazer os registros referentes a cada uma delas

```
mysql> SELECT A.id_cat,a.title,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_doc, title) FROM hb_docs WHERE id_cat = A.id_cat) AS retorno FROM hb_cats A ORDER BY a.title ASC;


+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id_cat | title     | retorno                                                  |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | Começando | 1Visão Geral,2Requisitos,3Intalação                   |
|      3 | Helpers   | 8Database,9Password,10Session,11Url,12Input,13Validações|
|      2 | O Básico  | 4Controladores,5Modelos,6Visualizações,7Erros          |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set
```

espero que ajude.

Comment: olha quase deu certo, veja o print, repare que esta listando todos iguais :/ http://i.imgur.com/8Toz1bR.png

Comment: é teria que ficar assim: http://i.imgur.com/sS7dPur.png, olha la os prints dad minha tabela, onte id 1 = começando, 2= o basico, 3 = helpers, e o que ta acontecendo é isso: http://i.imgur.com/v3cylJI.png ta tenso :/

Comment: Isso mesmo, a primeira consulta vai te trazer código e nome da categoria, por isso o GROUP BY ( Começando(1), Básico(2) e Helpers(3)). E com a subconsulta você pega o código de cada registros e tráz seus dados com a cláusula WHERE (no caso id_cat (1,2 ou 3) veja  A.category, A.id_cat) com o código que veio na consulta usando o GROUP_CONCAT(). Na subconsulta você diz: (trazer todos os registros onde id_cat = A.id_cat ).

Comment: Vou tentar arrumar, com as dicas que você me deu acho que deve ser possível, se eu conseguir volto aqui e marco a resposta como resolvido att.

Comment: É ta difícil vou dormir, amanha continuo, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Realizei um cenário e consegui chegar ao resultado esperado. editei a resposta. Veja se consegue finalizar, só lembrando que o retorno precisa ser tratado.

Comment: A consulta direta no phpmyadmin me retorna tudo corretamente, porém, na lógica no meu model ainda continua retornando como no print. :/

Comment: Eu acho que o problema está na exibição olha lá meu código na minha view, primeira vez em 3 anos mexendo com PHP que me enfio em uma gambiarra dessas kkkkkk

Comment: Coloca a query conforme sua lógica aqui getCategories(); e dê um print_r aqui getDocsCategories() para ver o retorno. Eu mandaria o $data para a view e daria um var_dump ou print_r() para ver o que ele traz.

Comment: Você vai mesmo ter que mexer na sua view. no seu primeiro foreach recebe 03 itens como id_cat, title e uma string longa retorno, para cada linha do primeiro o segundo foreach você faz usando um explode para tratar o retorno.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39967/discussion-between-guilherme-spinxo-and-gilberto-m-g).

Comment: marquei como resolvido, o que eu queria você me explicou e deu certo agora é só ajustes, estou agora com dificuldade em receber na view