# Relacionar Categorias com Subcategorias da mesma tabela com outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Relacionar Categorias com Subcategorias da mesma tabela com outra tabela

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

[image: Screen_Hunter_15_May_20_10_44.png]

Até aí acredito que a modelagem esteja ok, certo?

Aí no resultado eu gostaria de buscar os seguintes campos:

```
id_manual | titulo | arquivo | downloads | id_categoria | id_subcategoria | categoria | subcategoria -
```

Sendo que não gostaria de concatenar os campos categoria e subcategoria.

[image: Screen_Hunter_15_May_20_10_47.png]

Até estou fazendo a junção das duas tabelas, porém os campos não estão ficando certos, o que eu gostaria é que no campo categoria, ficasse o nome da categoria e caso tenha subcategoria o nome da subcategoria ficasse no campo subcategoria, consequentemente isso para os campos `id_categoria` e `id_subcategoria`.

Como eu poderia fazer isso sem concatenar os campos (fazer com campos separador)? ou somente filtrando usando o PHP?

Gostaria de fazer somente uma Query com MySQL pra isso, se for possível.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ordenar por categoria](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129108/ordenar-por-categoria)

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO Como poderia ser feito sem concatenar o resultado conforme na imagem 2 que postei? valeu

Comment: como assim concatenar o resultado? Explique melhor pra que eu possa tentar lhe ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO no post que você mencionou você utiliza um Sub-select o qual retorna uma coluna com vários registros utilizando o Group_Concat, o que eu gostaria é que retornasse os dois resultados em colunas separadas, exemplo: retornar o nome da categoria e subcategoria em campos separados. Não sei se isso seria possível. Tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você fala de subcategoria mas eu não vi esse campo nem ID nas duas tabelas, só vi id_categoria e id_categoria_pai. Onde está subcategoria?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer pode ser alcançado com o uso de joins. Exemplo:

```
select * from manuais_categorias as m 
left join manuais_categorias as n on m.id = n.id_pai 
LEFT JOIN manuais_tecnicos on manuais_tecnicos.id_categoria = m.id;
```

Exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a47065/5/2):

Comment: Tentei fazer este código, porém com vários registros os mesmos vem duplicados.

Comment: Pela comentários da resposta anterior acho que essa resposta não se adequa mais. Mas complementando, para resolver o problema da duplicidade basta trocar o segundo **LEFT JOIN** por **INNER JOIN**. Com essa abordagem nem todas as categorias serão mostrada, apenas as que tem um manual associado. Veja edição no link do [SQL Fiddle][1]:


  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c869/2/1

Comment: Infelizmente continua a repetir dados, eu coloquei aqui um SQL para exemplificar melhor, fiz o que você havia passado, da uma conferida: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/986fcf/6

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM nw_manuais_tecnicos AS mt
LEFT JOIN nw_manuais_tecnicos_categorias as mc USING (id_categoria)
GROUP BY mt.id_categoria
```

Comment: Com esse código, o resultado acaba repetindo várias vezes.

Comment: Usou o GROUP BY? Se não deu certo com m.id_pai, tente manuais_tecnicos.id_categoria

Comment: Mesmo resultado, se quiser conferir: [link]http://s33.postimg.org/cokczojm7/Screen_Hunter_15_May_23_09_56.png[link]

Comment: você pode gerar o SQL dele?

Comment: select * from manuais_categorias as m 
LEFT JOIN manuais_tecnicos on manuais_tecnicos.id_categoria = m.id;
GROUP BY m.id_categoria

Comment: Tenta assim....

Comment: Modifiquei minha resposta, tente dessa forma...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dfe8f/1

Comment: Coloquei o código SQL aqui, da uma conferida, não consegui com seu código: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/986fcf/3

Comment: Acabei de copiar o codigo aqui e executar lá no seu sqlfiddle, deu certo aparentemente.. veja ai http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/986fcf/4

Comment: Na verdade ainda não está certo hehehe.. Olha só, na coluna nome, o registro "Prédio de múltiplas unidades consumidoras" é uma Categoria pai, certo? logo no registro posterior "Teste 2", ele é uma subcategoria da categoria pai "Prédio de múltiplas unidades consumidoras", então o correto seria ter as colunas Categoria com "Prédio de múltiplas unidades consumidoras" nos dois registros, e a coluna subcategoria com o registro "Teste 2" apenas na última linha. Não sei se consegui explicar direito.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisar de um relacionamento com `nw_manuais_tecnicos_categorias`  e entre ela mesma para retorna a categoria PAI.

Veja o exemplo.

```
select m.id_manual , m.titulo , m.arquivo , m.downloads ,
Ca.id_categoria , CaPai.id_categoria as id_subcategoria , Ca.Nome as categoria ,  CaPai.Nome as subcategoria 
from nw_manuais_tecnicos as m 
join nw_manuais_tecnicos_categorias as Ca on Ca.id_categoria = m.id_categoria 
left JOIN nw_manuais_tecnicos_categorias as CaPai on CaPai.id_categoria = Ca.id_categoria_pai;
```

Aqui uso o left Join como você mesmo falou pode ter categoria que não tem pai.